# terraform module structure and tfvars files

Tags: terraform

I have a configuration which uses modules, this is its structure:

```
main.tf
       \modules
               \kubernetes_cluster
                                  \main.tf
                                  \variables.tf
```

At this stage I had no separate tfvars file, I relied on default values declared in the variables.tf file, and this worked fine. I then decided to create a tfvars file resulting in:

```
main.tf
       \modules
               \kubernetes_cluster
                                  \main.tf
                                  \variables.tf
                                  \variables.tfvars
```

At the same time I removed the default values from variables file, then when I ran:

```
terraform apply -target=module.kubernetes_cluster -auto-approve
```

I got errors complaining that I needed to pass my variables in as arguments due to the fact "They were missing", so I moved to this:

```
main.tf
variables.tf
variables.tfvars
                \modules
                \kubernetes_cluster
                                   \main.tf
                                   \variables.tf
```

this is what main.tf in the root module looks like:

```
module "kubernetes_cluster" {
  source  = "./modules/kubernetes_cluster"
  kubernetes_version  = var.kubernetes_version
  node_hosts          = var.node_hosts
}
```

When I run terraform apply I get prompted for the values of the variables. All I want to do is not rely on variable default values and to be able to run terraform apply from the root module directory without having to pass in variable values by hand, I suspect that my module structure somewhere along the line is not correct.

Comment: If you don't want to use default values, where the actual values are supposed to come from?

Comment: I though the whole idea of a tfvars file was that they were picked up from there ?

Comment: If I add -var-file = . . . everything runs OK

Comment: Yes. You have to explicitly use `-var-file`.

Comment: So it seems that the issue is that my understanding of how tfvars files work is incorrect

Comment: Supply as an answer that my understanding of how tfvars files work needs some, let’s say refinement, and I will mark this as the answer

Comment: Thanks, if you rename `variables.tfvars` to `terraform.tfvars` it should work automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have TF load `tfvars` **automatically**, the file [must be called](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) `terraform.tfvars`, not `variables.tfvars`. There are other possibilities:

> Terraform also automatically loads a number of variable definitions files if they are present:

> Files named exactly `terraform.tfvars` or `terraform.tfvars.json`.

> Any files with names ending in `.auto.tfvars` or `.auto.tfvars.json`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the   [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files), terraform automatically loads tfvars if:

- Either variable file name is terraform.var or terraform.var.json
- Or YOUR_NAME.auto.tfvar

So in your case renaming `variables.tfvars` to `variables.auto.tfvars` would work